# SDL why create textures on the heap instead of stack

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, sdl, heap-memory

So I've been reading over lazyfoos SDL2 tutorials and I was just curious how come all of the `SDL_Surface`/`SDL_textures` etc are created on the heap? I realize SDL itself was written in C and the functions accept/return pointers, but why not create the surface on the stack and pass a reference of it to the function? (Or dereference it when assigning)

Hopefully I've been clear. Here's a code snippet to further try to explain:

why this:

```
void pointer()
{
    SDL_Surface *windowsurface;
    SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_LoadBMP("asdf.bmp");
    SDL_BlitSurface(surface, 0, windowsurface, 0);
}
```

instead of this:

```
void stack()
{
    SDL_Surface windowsurface;
    SDL_Surface surface = *(SDL_LoadBMP("asdf.bmp"));
    SDL_Blit(&surface, 0, &windowsurface, 0);
}
```

If the latter is indeed possible, would you still need to call `SDL_FreeSurface`? If so this would ensure you won't leak any memory so I don't quite see the benefit of the former.

Hopefully this all makes sense, I'm still a rookie when it comes to SDL

Comment: It's most likely because SDL's objects have internal resources that the SDL libraries must keep track of. This requires all instantiation and destruction of SDL objects to be done directly by the library, with only the library being responsible for 100% of object lifetime management; hence the only possible implementation is heap-based allocations and destruction.

Comment: So i have to create all of the surfaces on the heap? The reason i'm asking is because I have a lot of classes with textures as members, and would like to avoid worrying about copy constructors & assignments for all of my classes.

Comment: In your second example the `windowsurface` is destroyed when the function exits. I would imagine that most textures need to outlive the function in-which they are created.

Comment: The usual solution is to have a single wrapper for native C objects, like the ones in the SDL library, use std::shared_ptr to reference the objects, and have the wrapper take care of destroying the native C object using the library's appropriate destructor function.

Comment: The stack size is, in general, is not suitable for images. The default linux stack size is 8M (ulimit -s to see).

Comment: You write a shared ptr or unique ptr wrapper (with custom deleter) forthe objects.  Now RAII has your back.  @olivecoder Images also tend to be variable in size, and C++ doesn't enjoy doing that with a stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of reasons for this but I will focus on just one. Specifically, in C++ there is no portable way to create an object of size unknown at compile time on the stack.

This is a substantial problem as a texture is of unknown size to the compiler as it does not know how large the data loaded into it will be. In C this can be somewhat helped with the use of VLAs however these are still inadvisable for large objects due to small stack sizes available on many OSes.

In addition to all this the texture may be implemented in GPU memory rather than main memory. This absolutely cannot be on the stack and must be managed by the graphics routines in whatever system is being used. These graphics systems often just provide an opaque pointer to a texture in GPU memory which can be freed or managed with provided routines.

Now you could argue that the handle structure could live in the stack at least but in reality this provides minimal savings as the vast majority of reads and writes will be to the texture itself and not to the handle object so optimising that has little value.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with this approach:

```
void stack()
{
    SDL_Surface windowsurface;
    SDL_Surface surface = *(SDL_LoadBMP("asdf.bmp"));
    SDL_Blit(&surface, 0, &windowsurface, 0);
}
```

First of all, the objects `windowsurface` and `surface` will be destroyed when the function exits because the part of the stack they were created on will be reclaimed for the calling function.

Secondly, when they are destroyed it will be done by calling an equivalent of `delete` which may not be the correct deleter for those objects. The library supplies its own delete functions that need to be called.

Lastly the assignment to `surface` of a bitmap object could be slow as bitmaps can be large. Assigning pointers is much much faster.

A safe way to manage objects allocated from the free store (heap) is to use *smart pointers*:

```
// create a special deleter that calls the correct function
// to delete the object
struct SDL_Surface_deleter
{
    void operator()(SDL_Surface* surface) const { SDL_FreeSurface(surface); }
};

// some type aliases for convenience
using SDL_Surface_uptr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, SDL_Surface_deleter>;
using SDL_Surface_sptr = std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface>;

SDL_Surface_uptr make_unique_surface(SDL_Surface* surface)
{
    return SDL_Surface_uptr{surface};
}

SDL_Surface_sptr make_shared_surface(SDL_Surface* surface)
{
    return {surface, SDL_Surface_deleter{}};
}

void smart_objects()
{
    // no need to delete this
    auto unique_surface = make_unique_surface(SDL_LoadBMP("asdf.bmp"));

    // no need to delete this either
    auto shared_surface = make_shared_surface(SDL_LoadBMP("asdf.bmp"));

    // stuff...
}
```

Lookup [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) in [The Manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Main_Page).

Comment: Thanks for the response! So using smart pointers I'm able to avoid creating copy constructors/assign? I think I'll need to look at smart pointers more.

Answer (score 0):

I also prefer to avoid pointers when not necessary, but many game programmers use pointers when not required, allocating pretty much anything large with new, making it global (!), and calling delete at the end.

There is a small advantage to using dynamic allocation (more than offset by the risk of pointer errors, IMJ).  When you assign between two objects, you need a copy ctor, which means you have to decide whether to share memory.  That's often a bad idea, and if you don't, your copy ctor may need to do a lot of work (whereas copying a pointer is very cheap).  Later versions of C++ obviate some of this problem, but not all.

But in SDL, you're really forced to by SDL's choice to deallocate not simply with delete or free, but with its special functions `SDL_FreeSurface`, `SDL_DestroyTexture`, etc.  For structures using such functions, you're just stuck.  Therefore SDL programmers allocate these things dynamically, even if they aren't hardcore game programmers who think everything in sight should be made a pointer.  You can write wrappers to clean things up a bit, but underneath, you're still stuck with their deletion routines.